# Need to keep the jar in my maven local repository

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to keep custom jar in local repository.Maven is already installed in eclipse.But coming to the command prompt it is showing as "The program 'mvn' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install maven"
If i install the maven and keep that jar in local repository,will it reflect eclipse pom?

Comment: You seem to be confused by what Eclipse and Maven are. Please refer to their main sites and help pages. What is the actual problem you have?

Comment: I need to keep the custom jar in my local repository.After keeping the pom is not getting reflected.I dont know whether I am using the different maven local repository   for eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to install maven on your system as suggested.
2. Now in eclipse go to Window -> Prefrences -> Maven -> installations and add that maven there.
3. Then install your custom jar to maven as suggested [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).

Comment: installed maven.Where can i find the path.I am unable to see where it is installed.I am using ubuntu.

Comment: From shell try one of these : 1. echo $M2_HOME 2. which mvn

Comment: showing an empty line.I am using ubuntu 16.04.Facing many problems.May be the issue because of this.After installation it has shown the installed path.In that path .m2 is not visible

Comment: If "$which mvn" is not returning anything then, it is not installed properly. Please refer http://maven.apache.org/install.html .

Comment: It is showing as /usr/bin/mvn But there is no M2_home to add into eclipse

Comment: please refer https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126644/discussion-between-techtrainer-and-smith).

Answer (score 0):

eclipse brings its own maven implementation.

If you want to run maven from command line you need to install it explicitly.